# union ordered select error

Tags: sql, select, union

I have a table titled mytable with these result

```
ID | name
----------
1  | one
2  | two
3  | three
4  | four
5  | five
```

I need this result

```
ID | name
----------
3  | three
1  | one
2  | two
4  | four
5  | five
```

Record '3 , three'  must be in the first line , then others will be showed after this record. Thank You ;

Comment: Please specify the database your using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select ID, NAME from 
    (select *, -1 as rnum from tb where id=3
    union all
    select *, ID as rnum from tb where id!=3 ) tb1
ORDER BY rnum ASC
```

here is the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ca9a/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable s where s.id=3
union all
select * from ( 
    select t.id,t.name from mytable t where t.id!=3
order by t.id) as q;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f6ce/12)

Comment: NO , wrong , it shows :

1  | one<br/>
2  | two<br/>
3  | three<br/>
4  | four<br/>
5  | five<br/>

I need the following :

----------
3  | three<br/>
1  | one<br/>
2  | two<br/>
4  | four<br/>
5  | five<br/>

Comment: @user2759163 i`ve tested it should rewrite it to wotk properly you can   use the link

Answer (score 0):

try this. it should work in PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLServer

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS ID,  'one' as NAME 
  UNION SELECT 2 , 'two'
  UNION SELECT 3 , 'three'
  UNION SELECT 4 , 'four'
  UNION SELECT 5 , 'five'

) AS MyDataSet
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID = 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard SQL, you can simply order by a value based on the row you want first (returning a lower value for that specific row than for all other rows), followed by ID.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name='three' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ID
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcebc/2).